# Not able to set is Identity key as Yes in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I just not created a new database with 2 tables in it. In a table, I have set a column as a primary key and trying to change its properties i.e. setting is Identity to YES, but am not able to do so.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: No it does not... It is currently set as "No" and in any case I am not able to change it to Yes or any other value from No.

Comment: Did you expand that option?  As I recall, the identity spec is actually grayed out and not alterable until you expand its little sub-tree.  Then in there you can actually just double click on IsIdentity and you should be all set.

Comment: That is correct, there is a + button which gives you a number of options regarding setting an identity.

Comment: Yes I did... :) Even my Identity Specification is set as "No"

Comment: @tech_learner: For a column to be identity it should be of type int. Are you sure your column type is not set to something else? And you are indeed looking at right column?

Comment: Hey gbs, the column is not set to type int. May be that could be the issue... I will set it to int and then try to make is identity to true. But I had one query, what if the column type is nchar. I have set it to nchar, because I have an employee table with employee id as PK. Employee id can be formed using numbers and characters as well. I am searching for its answer online, please share if anybody has any sort of idea on this. Thanks again :)

Comment: thks @tech_learner . my column was set to money instead of int :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have data in the table? You can't make an IDENTITY column if you do.

Comment: Ohh yes, I do have all the data into the columns.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the datatype is `int` and not something else.

You can't have an identity on a different type.

Answer (score 2):

Did you expand that option? As I recall, the identity spec is actually grayed out and not alterable until you expand its little sub-tree. Then in there you can actually just double click on IsIdentity and you should be all set

Made it an answer so I could put an image.  Let us know if this isn't the problem.

[image]

Comment: Yes I did... :) Even my Identity Specification is set as "No"

Answer (score 2):

The (Is Identity) field will also be greyed out if there is a Default Value or Binding set on the column.

Comment: This was the culprit for me

Answer (score 1):

***IDENTITY***

**If you want to retain the data for that particular column. you can use this method. New table creation with identity.**

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableName

(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),

EMPNAME varchar (25),

AGE INT

PRIMARY KEY(ID));

### Made By : Syed Baqar Hassan

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEbxQ.png